# Improve the performance on generating combinations

Tags: javascript

I know there are many posts about generating the combinations, however this question is quite different.

Here are the items:

```
var item = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

I would like to get the result as:

```
[
    [ ['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'] ],
    [ ['a'],['b','c'],['d'] ],
    [ ['a'],['b'],['c','d'] ],
    [ ['a'],['b','c','d'] ],
    [ ['a'],['c'],['b','d'] ],....
]
```

What I would like to generate is the unique combination of combination.

I have coded some for achieve the question, however it's very slow and bad in performance.

```js
function getCombinations(items) {
   var res = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      for (var j = i + 1; j <= items.length; j++) {
         var temp = items.slice(i, j);
         var remained = items.slice(0, i).concat(items.slice(j, items.length));
         if (remained.length > 0) {
            var combinations = getCombinations(remained);
            combinations.forEach(combination => {
               res.push([temp].concat(combination));
            });
         } else {
            res.push([temp]);
         }
      }
    }
   return res;
}

var item = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

console.log(getCombinations(item));
```

Comment: If the code is working, please post this on [codereview.se].